# get all esim profiles of my card Android API

Tags: java, android, react-native

I want to get all esim profiles of my esim card
How can i get it ?

Im trying this function

```java
    public void listESIMProfiles(Promise promise) {
        try {
            EuiccManager euiccManager = (EuiccManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.EUICC_SERVICE);
            List<UiccCardInfo> uiccCardInfos = euiccManager.getUiccCardsInfo();
            List<String> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
            for (UiccCardInfo uiccCardInfo : uiccCardInfos) {
                EuiccInfo euiccInfo = uiccCardInfo.getEuiccInfo();
                if (euiccInfo != null) {
                    profiles.add(euiccInfo.getEid());
                }
            }
            promise.resolve(profiles);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            promise.reject("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

but the method `getUiccCardsInfo` does not exists